# Make alias in a folder to be chosen

Tags: macos, finder, osx-mavericks, applescript, automator

I want to make an alias of selected files or folder in other folders, which I want to be able to choose each time from a pop-up window.
This was something that was available on previous OSX versions with a third part application that added contextual menu items. Now I am on Mavericks and I am sure it is possible to do but I cannot get it going.
Here is the script I created:

```
set thefile to selection
set thefolder to choose folder
tell application "Finder" to make new alias to thefile at thefolder
```

I saved the script as "Make alias in.scpt" and added it as a service with Automator.
When I run it I get the following error:

> "Finder got an error: Can’t get document \"Make alias in.scpt\"."
>   number -1728 from document "Make alias in.scpt"

I am obviously missing something, this being my absolute first script. Is there someone who could point me to the faults and explain how I should write it to make it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
set thefolder to choose folder
tell application "Finder"
    set mySelection to selection
    repeat with aSel in mySelection
        make alias to aSel at thefolder
    end repeat
end tell
```

EDIT
If you are using the script as a service:
Service receives selected files or folders in Finder

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell me
        activate
        set thefolder to choose folder
    end tell

    tell application "Finder"
        repeat with aSel in input
            make alias to aSel at thefolder
        end repeat
        reveal thefolder
    end tell
end run
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. It works! Thanks! Now, is it possible to show the chosen folder in which the aliases have been created? I added "Reveal Finder Items" in Automator after the script, but it shows the original files, not the aliases.

Comment: Also, but this is minimal, the "Choose folder" window that pops up is not automatically the front windows, is there a way to make it so?

Comment: Thanks again. I tried the second script, it does bring the "Choose folder" windows in front and it does show the new aliases. What is weird is that now when I run the service two aliases are made in the destination folder, one with the same name as the original file, plus one with the same name and the "alias" appendix added in the end.